# Ask & Bid yield calculation problem

Tags: bonds, yield, fixed-income, bid-ask, corporate-bonds

1. Does anyone know how the ask and bid yields are calculated on this corporate bond?

   [image: Screenshot]

   [image: Additional screenshot]

   I tried to use BEY calculation but I keep arriving at different answers.
2. Does anyone know what the $500K means?

If you need more info about the bond, please let me know. Cheers.

```
ASK 89.550(9.999%) x $500K
BID 85.000(11.562%) x $500K

Maturity date: 02’May’2025
Coupon: 6.75%
Par Value: 100
Call date: unknown
CUSIP: 316162227

Days to maturity: 1457 days
```

Comment: Here's an approximate calculation for the Ask: 100 - 89.55 = 10.45; 10.45 / 3.9918 = 2.62; 6.75 + 2.62 = 9.37; 9.37 / 89.55 = 10.46% . http://www.kbhscape.com/bond.htm .

Comment: @SSpring thanks for the try :)

Comment: The top "$500K" is the ask size, and the bottom "$500K" is the bid size.

Comment: @Flux you mean its issuance size?

Comment: @RonJab No. Refer to: [ask size](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/asksize.asp), [bid size](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/bidsize.asp).

Comment: @Flux thanks :)     Btw, any idea on how the ask yield is 9.999% and the bid is 11.562%?

Comment: Could you double-check the CUSIP? What is the ISIN of this bond?

Comment: This is probably a callable bond, and the yield is the yield-to-worst. The bond appears to be [TranspGasDelSur 6,75% 02/05/2025 Reg S](https://www.bourse.lu/security/USP9308RAZ66/265523) or [TranspGasDelSur 6,75% 02/05/2025 Rule 144A](https://www.bourse.lu/security/US893870AX30/265517). Check the prospectus for the early redemption dates.

Comment: @SSpring What does http://www.kbhscape.com do? I have not been able to figure it out.

Comment: @Flux Here is another image, with its CUSIP & another details. I tried to double check its CUSIP on another site but nothing came up https://ibb.co/ZNHrmJC

Comment: Buy the bond and receive 9.999% yield or short the bond and pay 11.562% yield ? Otherwise sell the bond to the market-maker and the market-maker receives 11.562% yield. The yield depends on the price paid for the bond ...

Comment: @RonJab The CUSIP you provided is incorrect. The correct CUSIP is P9308RAZ6. The ISIN is USP9308RAZ66.

Comment: Well, here's what happened. Multiple posters were showing up on this forum with incorrect bond pricings. The situation seemed like a scam occurring somewhere. Posters answering the questions seemed to be supporting the scams. Then finally the source of the problem was found to be an incorrect example in a Wikipedia article. Then next thing that happened is that a poster on the Math forum asked for an approximate yield-to-maturity calculation. And then an approximate, or an alternative, yield-to-maturity calculation was found with KBH Applications.

Comment: @Flux thanks. How did you find the right CUSIP with just the details I gave you. I tried to google the bond but to  find its prospectus and call date but to no avail.

Comment: @Flux I thought it was the CUSIP because normally on other bonds, when I quote that number on Bondsupermarket the bond sometimes comes up; but not always. But thank you for showing me it can be found on the Luxembourg stock exchange.

Comment: @Flux did you just copy & paste the ISIN to search for the bond on the site?

Comment: @RonJab I found that "Tragas" is short for "Transportadora de Gas del Sur", so I searched for "Transportadora de Gas del Sur 6.75 bond" on Google. Through the first few search results, I found that the bond is listed on the Luxembourg Stock Exchange. On the Luxembourg Stock Exchange's website, I found the prospectus for the bond. In the prospectus, I found the CUSIP and ISIN. The ISIN in the prospectus matched the ISIN in your second screenshot: USP9308RAZ66. That's how I knew that I found the correct bond. By the way, the ISIN contains the CUSIP.

Comment: @Flux thanks for the explanation, I also found out, that in  the bonds prospectus that it has 2 ISINs which I never knew until now that a security can have 2 ISINs https://ibb.co/yhkWgmL

Answer (score 3):

Yield for a coupon-bearing bond is not a simple closed-form calculation. You have tried a few approximations that may be close (or maybe not), but the [*exact* calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond_valuation) requires you to look at the current cost of the bond (including any accrued interest), all future cashflows (the coupons plus the final redemption), and calculate the equivalent interest rate of that investment.  To do that, you plug in an interest rate into the present value calculations (sum of the present value of all cash flows), and keep trying values until you get the exact present value (price) of the bond.

For this particular bond that matures in May of 2025, that means that there are 8 semi-annual cash flows of 33.75 (1,000 * 6.75% /2) and the final redemption of 1,000. With a price of 85 (plus ~1 week of accrued interest) that gives a yield of 11.562%

This bond is also *callable*, which can change the yield calculation a bit (what is the worst yield that I would get if the bond was called at one of its call dates). That's an *even more complex* calculation.

In other words, At what interest rate could you invest the cost of the bond (and the coupons as you receive them) and have the same amount in the end when the bond matures? If you buy the bond at 89.55, that would be (if the bond pays out to maturity) equivalent to putting it (and the coupons) in a savings account that pays 9.999% interest. But, you run the risk that the bond *won't* pay out, in which case you'll get much less than $1,000 back (if any) at the end.

> Does anyone know what the $500K means?

That means that someone is willing to buy $500k of bonds at that price. If someone wants to sell more than $500k, they may have to accept a lower price for any bonds after that $500k is fulfilled (it's the same concept as the number of shares in the order book for stocks)